# Jquery - Using an id to slide in content with slideToggle

Tags: jquery

I need to use the ID of a div to slide down its contents. At the moment it seems to be sliding down all the "fullMessage" divs and displaying their contents. I have looked at using `.parent()` and `.closest()` but I thought the id approach would be better, I may be wrong.

// JS

```
$('#messageBox .message .subject').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
       $('.fullMessage #' + id).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

// HTML

```
<div id="messageBox">
    <?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>
        <div class="message">
            <div class="subject">
                <a href="" id="<?php echo $message['id']; ?>">
                <?php echo $message['subject']; ?>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fullMessage" id="<?php echo $message['id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $message['message']; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You shouldn't have 2 elements with the same ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is `$('.fullMessage #' + id)`  this will find the element with the ID that is a child of `.fullMessage`.

Since `.fullMessage` has the ID, you want `$('.fullMessage#' + id)` (remove the space).  Though `.fullMessage` is redundant here, because you're already using the ID.

On another note, you really shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID (`$('#ID')` will get the first element with the ID).  I suggest you change the ID on `.fullMessage` to something like `message_id`.

```
<div class="fullMessage" id="message_<?php echo $message['id']; ?>">
```

Then you can change the selector to:

```
$('#message_' + id)
```

Comment: Changed the id and the selector, worked a treat. Thank you :)